# Apollo client resetStore calls graphQL/Mongoose query, resulting in an error?

Tags: reactjs, mongoose, graphql, apollo-client

This is my client-side function that handles clicking a Logout button:

```
    const client = useApolloClient();
    const [Logout] = useMutation(LOGOUT);

    const handleLogout = async (e) => {
        await Logout();
        const { data } = await props.fetchUser();
        if (data) {
            let reset = await client.resetStore();
        }
    };
```

This is my logout resolver (the mutation takes in no arguments and returns boolean):

```
logout:(_, __, { res }) => {
    res.clearCookie('refresh-token');
    res.clearCookie('access-token');
    return true;
}
```

For some reason, `client.resetStore()` executes a query I have called `getRegionPath`, which takes in a String. This function is only called in a few of my React components, locked behind an `auth`, so once logged out, these components are not accessible and cannot be rendered or routed to.

Here is my `getRegionPath` resolver.

```
getRegionPath: async (_, args) => {
    const {region_id} = args;
    const objectId = new ObjectId(region_id);
    const region = await Region.findOne({_id: objectId});
    if (region.parentRegion == null) {
        return [];
    }
    else {
        const path = await regionPath(region.parentRegion);
        return path;
    }
}
```

I have no idea why `client.resetStore()` might make a call to `getRegionPath`, none of my components with  that query ever run, yet I still get this error:

"Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters"

How could `resetStore()` possibly call another query? Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

After looking into it, it seems `resetStore()` refetches active queries. How can I make my `getRegionPath` query not be active? Here is where it is called conditionally:

```
{auth ?
<ul>
    <WNavItem>
        <Breadcrumbs user={props.user} currentRegion={currentRegion} handleSetCurrentRegion={handleSetCurrentRegion}/>
    </WNavItem>
</ul> : <></>}
```

And the component:

```
const Breadcrumbs = (props) => {
    console.log("getting path from breadcrumbs");
    const {data} = useQuery(GET_REGION_PATH, {variables: {region_id: props.currentRegion}}, {fetchPolicy: 'network-only'})
    
    if (data) { return (...) }
    else return (<></>)
};
```